# Why does my Vuex getter that loops over my cart items and returns the item count not update when I update the quantity of an item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to create a Vuex getter that will return the total quantity of items in my shopping cart, however, my current implementation seems to not work correctly.

I have the following component where I try to display the cart's item count:

```
<template>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <ul class='nav-ul'>
                <router-link to="/cart" tag='li'>Cart({{ cartItemsCount }})</router-link>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            cartItemsCount(){
                return this.$store.getters.cartItemCount
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that either my `cartItemCount` getter is not working right, or there's another issue with my code. Whenever I add `item1`, the counter goes up then when I add `item2`, the counter goes up again, but once I try to add `item1` or `item2` again in order to increase the quantity, the counter stops going up and I'm not quite sure why.

This is my Vuex cart module which has the getter and the function that adds a new item.

```
const cart = {
    state: {
        cart: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'test1',
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'test2',
                quantity: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    mutations: {
        ADD_CART_ITEM(state, part) {
            let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
                return item.id === part.id
            })

            if (productInCart) {
                productInCart.quantity += part.quantity
            } else {
                state.cart.push(part)
            }
        },
    },
    getters: {
        cartItemCount: state => {
            let itemCount = 0

            state.cart.forEach(item => {
                itemCount += item.quantity
            });

            return itemCount
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a proper answer to this one, but it has to do with the fact that, when you add the same item again, the item is changed but the array is not, so cartItemCount is not executed. You may need an state which is a proper list of ungrouped items, but maybe there's another solution. I don't know if vuex has an equivalent to `vm.$forceUpdate()`

Comment: It could also be that `cart` perhaps starts off as something other than array and isn't reactive

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407